# Youtube video Downloader Plugin how to install?

Tags: software-installation

i want youtube video downloader in chrome or firefox plugins. i am using Ubuntu 15.10 .
please help

Comment: Then go to their plugin stores and look for it! What else could we say?

Comment: @EduardoCola, you could also say that this has nothing to do with ubuntu and it's only related to either Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Firefox extensions can be searched for and downloaded from https://addons.mozilla.org/ regardless of your operating system.

Browser extensions are distributed by the browser's makers themselves (in this case Mozilla Foundation), and can be installed directly from inside the browser, as their code is written in JavaScript and other browser-specific languages, so they have nothing to do with the platform.

Now, since I'm already writing an answer...

I personally use [YouTube Video and Audio Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-video-and-audio-dow/?src=search). The main appeals are that it integrates with my download manager ([DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/?src=search)), offers a lot of download options, is easy to use, is featured, and unlike another extension I tried, it doesn't advertise for websites nor have user tracking "features".

But just like any type of extension, a brief search in Mozilla's extensions website reveals many more options. It's not that I don't like them, it's that I didn't bother trying each one of them, since the aforementioned extension settled the deal for me. YMMV.

Since you are new to extensions, you are advised to follow some security guidelines before installing any new extension that you discover. For starters, those marked as "Featured" are most probably safe. If they're not featured, at least check their popularity / number of users (if it's in the order of hundreds of thousands or millions, then it's probably in the green; absolutely avoid the ones which still have like a few hundred users, as they haven't been tested enough to verify their legitimacy), and check the ratings and reviews for anyone mentioning malware, "a scandal", or something like that.

If not sure about some extension, it wouldn't hurt to paste its name in Google along with keywords like "virus", "trojan", "scandal", etc., which reveals any discussions about this matter, or ask an experienced person about it. If all fails, it might be better to do without it. Likely a dozen other popular alternatives exist.

Now, for a more Ubuntu-related answer: You can also install the package `youtube-dl` (using `apt-get install youtube-dl`). It's not really a browser extension, but a separate command-line program for downloading videos from YouTube (and a ton more websites). Usage is quite simple: Just copy the URL, open a terminal, type `youtube-dl` and paste the URL after it. Options may be used to specify the desired format and quality, among many other things. Try `youtube-dl --help` and `man youtube-dl` for detailed help.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox plugin 'Video DownloadHelper' works well with Youtube and is usually updated to match Youtube changes.:

[Video Download Helper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/)

I see there is also a Chrome version but I have not tested this...